Is there a subspace in which a curve projected onto a sphere does not change it's number of self-intersections?
Suppose that I have a continuous curve $\Gamma(t) : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$. Let $q \in \mathbb{R}^3$ and project $\Gamma (t)$ onto a unit sphere at $q$. Let $k$ be the number of self-intersections in the projected curve $\Gamma_q(t)$. Is it possible to find some $d \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that the number of self-intersections of $\Gamma_{q+d}(t)$ is also $k$?

Can you clarify your quantifiers? Given curve $\Gamma$ and point $q$, you seek a displacement vector $d$ (depending on $\Gamma$ and $q$) such that the self-intersection number of the projection is unchanged?

@SammyBlack I struggle to formulate the question precisely. Feel free to suggest an edit if you understand. But I seek any information on the set $S$, $d \in S$ for a given $\Gamma$ and $q$.  Is it empty?  Does it form a line? a plane? it doesn't seem so. What can we say about $S$?

Do you mean project radially? Then the cardinality of self-intersection points of the projection does not depend on the radius.

@MoisheKohan Yes. The radius of the sphere doesn't matter. $\Gamma_q(t) = \frac{\Gamma(t) - q}{\lVert \Gamma(t) - q \rVert}$

Then you should write an answer to your own question.

@MoisheKohan I'm interested by the set of $d \in \mathbb{R}^3$ that have the same intersections  $k$ for a given $\Gamma$ and $q$. I don't see how the radius being irrelevant provides an answer.

If it's not clear: $\Gamma_{q+d}(t) = \frac{\Gamma(t) - q - d}{\lVert \Gamma(t) - q - d \rVert}$.

Oh, sorry, I misread your question.
